# Image not appears in the view (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a viewcontroller which can't display the image,here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

        NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];

        if (image) {

            [imageView initWithImage:image];

            scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
            scrollView.bounces = NO;
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
            scrollView.delegate = self;

            [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
            [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        }   
    });

    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
```

It worked very well previously,but after I have made some changes in other viewcontrollers(I didn't make any changes in this one), it didn't show the image anymore, I can't figure out what's going on.

when I use "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" function to dismiss this viewcontroller ,  I did see the image at that moment;  and when I make the app background and put it front again, the image appears magically.

I 'am totally confused!  any suggestion?

my problem got solved by putting these code in the main quene, thank you for all your attention.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];

    if (image) {
        [imageView initWithImage:image];
        scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
        scrollView.bounces = NO;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
and also be sure that your imageView is already allocated some memory.

Comment: it didn't work.   scrollView and imageView are initialized from xib file.  I did see the image at the moment when dismissing this viewcontroller. but it didn't show correctly.

Comment: imageview is also having (0,0)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to be somewhere else, or a problem with the image itself. It wouldn't have caused a problem here unless you changed it somewhere else in your code. From what I can tell, all the code here is completely correct. Check in the other view controllers you added and also in the XIBs to see if everything is connected correctly. Even if it is, reconnect the image view and scroll view. Is the scroll view displaying correctly?

Comment: I do nothing else just  making  the app background and putting it front again in the simulator, the image appears correctly. that 's wha t confuse me mostly.

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting things in the XIBs? That sometimes straightens out odd bugs

Comment: actually , there are more codes in the DownloadQuene, the debug result tells me that all these codes have beening successfully executed. but it did't show the executing results (like removing some subview) in the screen,only when making the app background and putting it front again, the results shows in the screen ,like what i have described before.

Comment: Well like others have said, try manually setting the size to something other than (0,0), and maybe frame while you're at it

Answer (score 0):

can you debug and check what is the size of scrollView after this:
scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
else try keeping it static and try, if it shows the result then its problem with your content size as you keeping it image.size.

Comment: yes , I can debug, the NSlog result of the image.size is (0,0), but the image really exists.

Answer (score 0):

then type 
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);

it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the frame of image view. if its (0,0) it will not show the result.

and replace image with image view in below code.

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

Comment: I don't think that's the reason , because in the previous version, the NSLog result is also (0,0), and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: but there is a difference, image and imageView are different. and your scroll should be of image view size.